# BackgroundTransfer cannot move files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am having problem downloading files using Background transfer. After completion of download when moving file, it gives you an exception `Operation not permitted`

```
void addTransferRequest(string fileName)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
           return;
     string filePathToDownload = string.Empty;
     filePathToDownload = activeReciter.DownloadURL;
     filePathToDownload += fileName;

     Uri transferUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(filePathToDownload), 
                               UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new 
     BackgroundTransferRequest(transferUri);
     transferRequest.Method = "GET";
     transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.AllowBattery;

     Uri downloadUri = new Uri(DataSource.TEMPDOWNLOADLOCATION + fileName, 
                               UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
     transferRequest.DownloadLocation = downloadUri;
     transferRequest.Tag = fileName;

     transferRequest.TransferStatusChanged += 
       new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>
                                              (transfer_TransferStatusChanged);
     transferRequest.TransferProgressChanged += new 
     EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transfer_TransferProgressChanged);

     try
     {
       BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
       chapterFileNames.Dequeue();
     }
     catch (InvalidOperationException)
     {
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }
}
void transfer_TransferStatusChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
{
   ProcessTransfer(e.Request);
}
void transfer_TransferProgressChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
{
}
private void ProcessTransfer(BackgroundTransferRequest transfer)
{
    switch (transfer.TransferStatus)
    {
       case TransferStatus.Completed:
       if (transfer.StatusCode == 200 || transfer.StatusCode == 206)
       {
             using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = 
                    IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                 {
                   try
                   {
                      string filename = transfer.Tag;
                      string folderPath = string.Format(@"{0}{1}\{2}\", 
                        DataSource.DOWNLOADLOCATION, activeReciter.ReciterID, chapter.ChapterID);
                      string fileFullPath = folderPath + filename;

                      if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists(Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath)))
                          isoStore.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(folderPath));

                      if (isoStore.FileExists(fileFullPath))
                          isoStore.DeleteFile(fileFullPath);

                      isoStore.MoveFile(transfer.DownloadLocation.OriginalString, fileFullPath); 
                      //Excpetion is thrown here
                      RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occured: " + ex.Message + transfer.Tag, "Error", 
                                 MessageBoxButton.OK);
                return;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

When moving file, it throws exception, I don't know what is wrong with moving (this happens on some of the files not all files).

Comment: Have you tried: `string savedLocation = transfer.DownloadLocation.OriginalString;` then RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId); and then move your file? The problem might be with the fact that you want to move file which is used by BackgroundTransfer.

Comment: Thanks, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx), under `File System Restrictions` section:

> You can create any additional directory structure you choose
>   underneath the root “/shared/transfers” directory, and you can copy or
>   move files after the transfer is complete to ensure that the
>   background transfer service does not modify the files, but attempting
>   to initiate a transfer using a path outside of the “/shared/transfers”
>   directory will throw an exception.

Make sure you are not trying to move your file outside from the `/Shared/Transfers` folder.